# Removing values less than the median

Tags: matlab, median

If I know the median of an array, say the median is d, how can i remove all the values that are not greater than or equal to that value? I know you could binarize the image to a certain threshold but I want to still have a gradient so that I can see which pixels are more active than others. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"?  Delete columns and rows?  Replace by NaN?  Replace by the median?

Comment: Sorry I wasnt clear there, for my current purpose replacing the value that is less than the median with a 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indexing with a boolean mask is good at this:

```
d = median(img);
img(img < d) = 0;
```